# Can't apply material colours to the Lego Blender tutorial I'm following

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrEHoaq6QFE) on using Geometry Nodes to turn a beach ball into lego pieces.

Everything works correctly until the step at 6m10s.
The lego model is supposed to suddenly take the colour of the material at each lego brick position.  Mine stays a dull orange colour.

I am using Blender v3.61, but he was using Blender v3.4

What am I doing wrong?

My .blend file:
[image]

Node setup:
[image: node setup]

Shading setup:
[image: shading setup]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just forgot to connect sample index to store attribute node like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

Basically you can say, if there is a node with "no output used" - > there must be something wrong or superfluous.